# How to set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in PHP?

Tags: php, chmod

I think my question explains everything. I want to use php's **chmod() function** to set a **777 permission** on a folder, its subfolders and files.

Any Help is appreciated. THX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
chmod("Folder",0770);
```

function in php allow you to change permission of file and 
for recursive change use exec

```
exec ("find /path/to/folder -type d -exec chmod 0770 {} +");//for sub directory
exec ("find /path/to/folder -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +");//for files inside directory
```

make sure that your webserver have write access to the Folder.

Check these for more detail
http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_chmod.asp

Answer (score 2):

There's a long winded way to do it in php, I would personally do it via the command line which PHP can interact with.

On the command line (Linux/Unix) you can do `chmod options permissions filename`

To recursively change permissions you would do `chmod -R 0777 masterFile`

So in PHP you would do `exec("chmod -R 0777 masterFile");`

-R means recursive so it would go to your sub-folders

The long winded way to do in PHP alone would be to get an array of the sub folders and do a foreach loop and run the chmod() function in PHP, but this way is cleaner.

See [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm) for more information on linux/unix chmod

Hope this helps.